# Firebase database doesn't return data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I am currently trying to make an account page for users using data from Firebase auth, database, and storage. The only problem with the code is that the text and images that need data from the database(username and profile picture) are appearing as undefined so it seems like the database isn't returning data

the code:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.13.0/firebase-app.js"
import {  getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword, signOut, onAuthStateChanged } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.13.0/firebase-auth.js';
import { getDatabase, set, ref } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.13.0/firebase-database.js';
import { getStorage, ref as storageRef, getDownloadURL } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.13.0/firebase-storage.js'


const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: ""
};

//Initiate firebase services
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app)
const database = getDatabase(app)
const storage = getStorage(app)
//Get image folder from storage
const imageFolder = storageRef(storage, "gs://betterbadgeworld.appspot.com/profile-pictures")
//Get user UID and accountData
let user = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user)=>{
    if (user) {
      var user = auth.currentUser
      return user
    }
    else {
      return
    }
})

let accountData = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user)=>{
    if (user) {
      var userUID = user.uid
      var accountData = ref(database, 'users/' + user.uid)
      console.log(accountData)
      return accountData
    }
    else {
      return
    }
})

//Add username and profile picture to website with accountData
function initializeData(accountData) {
//Get profile picture file name
let userProfilePicture = accountData.profilePicture + ".png"
//Set username in text box
const usernameText = document.createTextNode(accountData.username)
const usernameBox = document.getElementById('username')
usernameBox.appendChild(usernameText)
//Get profile picture div, make gs:// link, and get downloadURL for it
const profilePicBox = document.getElementById("profile-picture")
var profileGSLink = imageFolder + "/" + userProfilePicture
var profileLink = getDownloadURL(storageRef(storage, profileGSLink))
//Make image element and use profileLink as source
let img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = profileLink;
profilePicBox.appendChild(img);
}

initializeData(accountData)
```

the code that isn't returning the data:

```js
let accountData = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user)=>{
    if (user) {
      var accountData = ref(database, 'users/' + user.uid)
      console.log(accountData)
      return accountData
    }
    else {
      return
    }
})
```

Comment: Your code isn't actually reading data from the database yet. Have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once to learn how to read data.

Comment: Thanks! I finally got it working. Stupid of me not to check the docs.